# Raspberry Pi repeater with only one wlan adapter

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, raspberry-pi

I would like to use a Raspberry Pi (the old B model) and one (1) wlan stick as a repeater. Is this possible?

I use 2.4Ghz to connect to the AP (=>WAN) and 5GHz to operate as AP. I need a virtual interface created by "iw". All tutorials I found use 2 wlan sticks.

Can this work or are there any technical limitations which make a second wlan stick necessary?

Answer (score 1):

If your USB wlan stick supports at least one AP and one STA interface simultaniously with different channels, then yes, you can do that with this single USB stick.

However, hardware that can do this is not common (though it does exist). Check the `valid interface combinations` in the output of `iw list`, in particular look if `#channels` is big enough for the AP/STA combination line you want to use.

No, I can't tell you which particular brand of USB WLAN sticks will allow this - manufacturers like to put different chips in USB WLAN sticks with the same brand name, and even if you get the USB vendor and device id for the brand name, it needs a bit of googling to find out if the stick supports it.